# Importing From Google Analytics into AdWords

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

When importing from Google Analytics into AdWords is it possible to have Goals in GA with different campaigns trigger a different conversion in AdWords.

i.e. I want:
conversions for Goal 1 in Analytics with Campaign A to trigger Conversion X in Adwords
conversions for Goal 1 in Analytics with Campaign B to trigger Conversion Y in Adwords

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The conversions would be split across the campaigns anyway, so out of sheer curiosity, why?

Comment: The customer I am serving wants a breakdown of incoming traffic being funneled into one of 5 goals depending on certain criterion and for each of those goals a separate campaign in adwords for each of the channels in each individual goal.
It's complex but the customer is always right :)

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine creating two properties that would filter on campaigns with seperate goals for each property. Simply naming the goals Campaign #1, #2 etc. should give you what you're looking for, no?

Comment: Unfortunately having separate properties is not an option. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: What are your goals? A specific page? You could set a goal for a page when it has the campaign name in its url?

Comment: A goal is a pseudo page-hit representing a phonecall and it is not possible to pass the campaign information into this virtual pagehit as part of the querystring, nor is it possible to hit a different pseudo-page based on campaign information.
Sorry this is all so complicated.

Comment: Then I'd recommend using 5 telephone numbers; one for each campaign. (a different phone number is displayed corresponding to the campaign name/ID in the URLs querystring)

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible either since the number the customer sees cannot be controlled based on campaign data. They are simply shown a dynamic number from a pool of numbers which all route to the same destination. It sounds like what the customer needs isn't possible.

Comment: Ugh. My last suggestion would be timestamping the call and use some sort of proximity algorithm to couple online traffic with call data.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll have a look at what I can do.

Comment: The ugliest method: assuming you have 5 campaigns for 5 products/services - phone menu. Log the selection and bind it to a campaign. Also assuming you can differentiate between natural and paid traffic.